# check the array list size

Tags: java

How to check the sizeof array list in java without get error exception from the compiler if the arraylist is not been initialised.
I have tried the following but it does not work. and I got this message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

```
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
if (str.size()>0)
```

Comment: That code seems to be OK, are you sure that exceotion comes from that lines?

Comment: That code does not throw that exception unless you've discovered some new severe bug.

Comment: If the *size* of your collection is `1` then the only valid index is `0`.

Comment: Yes that is the problem because I used loop for(int i=0;i<=str.size();i++), while I remove the equal its work very goos.

Comment: str.isEmpty() is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in the code you posted that would throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I assume you were calling `str.get(0)` without the size check before?

Anyway, your code is fine, i.e. you should be able to extend it to do something like the following:

```
List<String> someStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
...
if (someStrings.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("First element of list is: " + someStrings.get(0));
} else {
    System.out.println("List is empty");
}
```

However, for cleanliness I would suggest using `if (!someStrings.isEmpty())` instead, which checks the same thing as `if (someStrings.size() > 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

By initialised do you mean if an object has been assigned to a reference

With the code

```
List<String> str;
```

If you call str.size() it will throw a null pointer exception as you have not assigned an object to this list reference.

To assign a reference then you can do

```
List<String> str = new Arraylist<String>();
```

str is now pointing at an array list object.

You can now call

```
str.isEmpty()
```

to see if the list has any contents.

Lists are [zero based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) so if you call str.get(0) then you will get a IndexOutOfBounds exception. You cannot get the first element (index 0) as there is nothing in there

If you add an element

```
str.add("hello")
```

then you can call

```
str.get(0)
```

which will return "hello"

If you call str.get(1) then again you will get an IndexOutOfBound because index 1 is actually the second element in the array list and this does not exist.